# White spot on generated image CycleGAN

Tags: conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to implement cyclegan. However, it looks like I always get white spots on my generated images even after 10 or 25 epochs. I am wondering what could be wrong? should I continue training and the problem would just go away? or is there any hint on how to solve this problem?

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HePdE.png)

Answer (score 0):

White spots are results from clipping your models output values that are too large when plotting the image.

In the Documentation of [matplotlib.imshow()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) it says:

> (...) an image with RGB values (0-1 float or 0-255 int)
> (...) Out-of-range RGB(A) values are clipped.

Without knowing your architecture, I would:

1. review your activation functions within the model and the final activation of your generator.
2. check your loss function, probably high output values are favoured by your loss objectvive
3. try training for more epochs, probably the model learns to avoid clipping by itself.